# news linkhandler (TYPO 8) and detailpage from category

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-8.x

When using the new linkhandler in TYPO3 like the link below:

https://usetypo3.com/linkhandler.html

i only have one parameter for the detail page:

```
config.recordLinks.tx_news {
    typolink {
        parameter = {$myConstants.newsDetailPid}
}
}
```

How can ich change the linkhandler (hook etc.) in order to get the detail page from the news Category (sys category)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
config.recordLinks.tx_news {
    typolink {
        parameter.stdWrap.cObject = CONTENT 
        parameter.stdWrap.cObject { 
            table = sys_category 
            select { 
                pidInList = 100
                # pid of category records 
                max = 1
                selectFields = sys_category.single_pid AS detailPid 
                join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid 
                where = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = { field: uid } 
                where.insertData = 1 
                andWhere.stdWrap.intVal = 1 
                andWhere.stdWrap.stripHtml = 1 
            }     
            renderObj = TEXT 
            renderObj.field = detailPid 
            renderObj.wrap = | 
        }   
        additionalParams.data = field:uid
        additionalParams.wrap = &tx_news_pi1[news]=|
        useCacheHash = 1
    }   
}
```

https://www.clickstorm.de/blog/linkhandler-typo3/

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. Additionally please add the key points from the page you linked to your post (especially since the page you linked is in german).

Answer (score 0):

You find the documentation of the linkhandler integration here:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/Changelog/8.6/Feature-79626-IntegrateRecordLinkHandler.html

There you can see that you can specify an own class for the handling. No hooks are provided as far as I can see.

Comment: Even when you change the class:

TCEMAIN.linkHandler.tx_news {
    #handler = TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\LinkHandler\RecordLinkHandler
    handler = Vendor\YourExt\Hooks\RecordLinkHandler
you cannot change the processing of the link.

The Link is build here:
https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Typolink/DatabaseRecordLinkBuilder.php

I don't really know how to change the link according your own rules.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the next upcoming version of ext:news, see this [change](https://github.com/georgringer/news/commit/b1cae28b232c36d5c6b6d950f9f8b393f08d351a) for details.

By using the following TypoScript

```
config.recordLinks.tx_news {
    typolink {
        # Detail page
        parameter.cObject = USER
        parameter.cObject {
            userFunc = GeorgRinger\News\Service\LinkHandlerTargetPageService->process
            news.data = field:uid
            # Page used if no detail page is set in the category
            fallback = 123
        }
        additionalParams.data = field:uid
        additionalParams.wrap = &tx_news_pi1[controller]=News&tx_news_pi1[action]=detail&tx_news_pi1[news]=|
    }
}
```

and the according userfunc

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace GeorgRinger\News\Service;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer;

/**
 * This file is part of the "news" Extension for TYPO3 CMS.
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please read the
 * LICENSE.txt file that was distributed with this source code.
 */
class LinkHandlerTargetPageService
{

    /** @var ContentObjectRenderer */
    public $cObj;

    public function process(string $content = '', array $configuration = []): int
    {
        $fallbackPageId = (int)($configuration['fallback'] ?? 0);

        $newsId = (int)$this->cObj->stdWrapValue('news', $configuration, null);
        if ($newsId === 0) {
            return $fallbackPageId;
        }

        $singlePid = $this->getSinglePidFromCategory($newsId);
        return $singlePid ?: $fallbackPageId;
    }

    /**
     * Obtains a pid for the single view from the category.
     *
     * @param int $newsId
     * @return int
     */
    protected function getSinglePidFromCategory(int $newsId): int
    {
        $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
            ->getQueryBuilderForTable('sys_category');
        $categoryRecord = $queryBuilder
            ->select('title', 'single_pid')
            ->from('sys_category')
            ->leftJoin(
                'sys_category',
                'sys_category_record_mm',
                'sys_category_record_mm',
                $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('sys_category_record_mm.uid_local', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('sys_category.uid'))
            )
            ->where(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('sys_category_record_mm.tablenames', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('tx_news_domain_model_news', \PDO::PARAM_STR)),
                $queryBuilder->expr()->gt('sys_category.single_pid', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter(0, \PDO::PARAM_INT)),
                $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($newsId, \PDO::PARAM_INT))
            )
            ->orderBy('sys_category_record_mm.sorting')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->execute()->fetch();
        return (int)$categoryRecord['single_pid'];
    }

}
```

Of course you can copy the PHP Class to your site package and adopt the namespaces in the TS as well to have it working in your installation